# how i can get by values use function find in model by node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, nodejs-server

I wrote code in node.js for find result from model mongoDB use mongoose
but i want get the result that include status equal waiting or accepted

This is my code that finds me results with waiting status

```
const Booking= require('../model/Booking')

displayBookings: async(req,res)=>{
    console.log('ok get')
    try {
      Booking.find({owner:req.params.id, status:'waiting'}).populate('driver').exec((err,result)=>{
        if(result){
        res.json({result:result})
      }
        else 
        res.json({error:err})
      })
    } catch (err) {
      res.json(err)
    }
  },
```

And this my routing code

```
const ControllerBooking=require('../conroller/booking')
router.get('/displayBookings/:id', ControllerBooking.displayBookings)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
Booking.find({ owner: req.params.id, 
               status: { $in: ['waiting', 'accepted']} })
```

[MongoDB official Documentation for $in operation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)